# yolov5 model ensembling using pytorch

Tags: python, yolov5

Is it possible to ensemble 2 models in pytorch similar to the yolov5 documentation?

https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/model_ensembling/

I tried the yolov5 documentation and it worked but need to integrate with pytorch and I also tried integrate the one yolov5 model to pytorch using torch library and it worked.Actually I need to integrate 2 models and need to predict the inference combined